# Submit User Form Data to another workbook

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have created a User Form in VBA so that call centre staff can submit their numbers to our tracking spreadsheet at the end of each day. In its current design, the form successfully submits data to another sheet in the workbook. As I discovered, macro-enabled spreadsheets can't be shared (each staff member will submit at roughly 4pm), so I am looking at making a copy of the user form spreadsheet for each staff member (around 15) and directing it to submit to a shared spreadsheet every day.

**i.e. 15 or so staff members use "User Form.xlsm" to submit to "Tracking Spreadsheet.xlsx" all around 4pm each day.**

Q1: Do I need to make the "Tracking Spreadsheet.xlsx" a Shared workbook in case more than one staff member submits their end of day form at once?
Q2: Do I need to insert VBA code in "User Form.xlsm" that actively opens "Tracking Spreadhseet.xlsx" or can I just reference "Tracking Spreadhseet.xlsx"?

Q3: Where have I gone wrong in the code below? I'm new to VBA. I have structured my code for the submission button as follows, but it just adds data to the Daily_Tracking_Dataset sheet in the current workbook, rather than the new one: 
First, I tried to *change the workbook*, 
then i *make the relevant sheet in the workbook active*, 
then I *determine the first empty row*, 
then I *transfer the information* from the form's textboxes to the new workbook.

```
Private Sub Button_Submit_Click()

'Change Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("G:\Tracking Spreadsheet.xlsx")

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Daily_Tracking_Dataset active
Daily_Tracking_Dataset.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = lstName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtROIT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtROISub.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtRefsT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = txtRefsC.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = txtRefsSub.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = txtReSubT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = txtReSubSub.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I ended up using the emptyrow method below:
    'Begin Transfer Information and Change Workbook
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("G:\Time To Complete Dataset.xlsx")

```
'Determine emptyRow
Dim emptyRow As Long
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("daily_tracking_dataset").Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
With nwb.Sheets("daily_tracking_dataset")
'Datebox
.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = CDate(txtDate.Text)
'Listbox
.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = lbName.List(lbName.ListIndex)
'Textbox
.Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtROT.Value
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_afterupdate()

Dim pro As Workbook

Set pro = Workbooks.Open("F:\DOCUMENTS\Proration.xlsm")

Workbooks("proration").Sheets("sheet1").Range("i20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

pro.Save
pro.Close True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q1/Q2: yes, you will need to add code to open the worksheet, and it may be better to open it Shared, at least if you do not save and close the tracking spreadsheet file immediately after inserting the data.

Did you try an Access database or something similar, where you can more easily add the required information and do not need to worry about concurrent accesses to the data "sheet"?

Regarding Q3: you did not state what is going wrong with your code at the moment.

**Edit:**
Regarding Q3: Try using something like `nwb.Sheets( "daily_tracking_dataset" ).Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value` and be aware that `emptyRow` also needs to be determined using `nwb`, e.g. using a combination of `Offset` and `Move(xlDown)` (see [Excel: Move selection to next blank row in specific column, and enumerate selection by date and type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527246/6206)).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use an Access database, as we don't have that available at our company, so it would need to be an Excel solution. 

Q1/2 I thought i was opening the workbook with the following:
'Change Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("G:\Tracking Spreadsheet.xlsx")

but instead it remains in the current workbook. What code would I use to open the workbook, add the row from the submission form, then save and clsoe the workbook?

For Q3, my example adds the form data to the current workbook, and doesn't open the new workbook or interact with that workbook at all

Comment: If the file is already open, it won't be open again. Else, it will easily be possible to address the newly opened workbook, e.g. by using `nwb.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value = "text"`.

Comment: So I think i followed the comments, but my new code comes up with a 438 error - Object doesn't support this property or method:
Private Sub Button_Submit_Click()

'Change Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("G:\Recruitment WA\WA PROJECTS\CKJV\Account Management\Zac's Drafts\Time to Complete Tracker - Zac's Draft.xlsx")

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Daily_Tracking_Dataset active
nwb.Daily_Tracking_Dataset.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
nwb.emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
nwb.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Comment: You are right, there was a sheet missing for the call to nwb cells. However, it always helps to say where VBA says the error is, i.e. try your code by stepping through it.

Comment: When I step through the code, I receive errors at nwbDaily_Tracking_Dataset.Activate; nwb.emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1; and all nwb.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value statements.

What do you mean when you say 'there was a sheet missing for the call to nwb cells'? How should I be coding this so that it successfully changes to the other workbook, selects the appropriate sheet, and adds records to the nearest emptyrow? I feel like i'm close but i'm missing something obviously

Comment: Use `nwb.Sheets("daily_tracking_dataset").Cells`... also use the same format for your call to activate. Regarding learning VBA please see the numerous answers here on SO.